# For what values of $t$ are the vectors $(2, 1, 1), (2, t, 2t)$ linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

$2(1, \frac {1}{2}, \frac {1}{2}) + t(\frac {2}{t}, 1, 2) = 0$ implies these vectors are linearly dependent for any value of $t$ because one of the coefficients is not $0$. Do you agree?

Comment: Do you claim that this equation holds for all $t \neq 0$, or do you want to find out for which values of $t$ it holds? Because it does not hold for all $t \neq 0$.

Comment: If $p$ denotes the equation mentioned in the body then $p$ is a statement that is not true. Consequently *any* statement of the form $p\implies q$ is true. You could fill in for $q$ the statement "$(2,1,1)$ and $(2,t,2t)$ are linearly dependent vectors".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning doesn't work. For one thing, what does $(\frac2t,1,2)$ mean if $t=0$? For another, if $t\ne 0,$ then $2(1, \frac {1}{2}, \frac {1}{2}) + t(\frac {2}{t}, 1, 2) = (2,1,1)+(2,t,2t)=(4,1+t,1+2t),$ and this is certainly not the $0$ vector.

Instead, suppose that $$a(2,1,1)+b(2,t,2t)=(0,0,0)$$ for some constants $a,b.$ Then we have the system: $$2a+2b=0\\a+bt=0\\a+2bt=0$$ Equivalently, multiplying the first equation by $\frac12$ and the second equation by $2,$ we have the equivalent system: $$a+b=0\\2a+2bt=0\\a+2bt=0$$ Subtracting the third equation from the second yields $a=0,$ whence substitution into the first equation yields the desired conclusion.

Comment: Since we didn't give $t$ any value and $a = b = 0$, it means for ant value of $t$, the vectors are independent, correct?

Comment: Correct! ${}{}$

Comment: The conclusion stated in the question is that the vectors are dependent (not independent as you prove them to be).

Comment: @drhab: Oops! I misread that. :-\

Answer (score 0):

solve $$x(2,1,1)+y(2,t,2t)=(0,0,0)$$ with real numbers $x,y$
from here we get
$$y(t-1)=0$$
and
$$y(2t-1)=0$$
can you proceed?

Comment: $x = -yt → 2(-yt) + 2b = 2y(-t + 1) = 0 → 1 – t = 0 → t  = 1$. 

Then $x = -y$ and $-y + 2yt = y(-1 + 2y) = 0$ so that $y = 0$ and $x = -0 = 0$?

Comment: we get $y=0$ or $t=1$ and $t=1/2$ which is impossible

Comment: if $y=0$ then $x=0$ which is impossible

Answer (score 0):

Your computation fails for $t = 0$. You want to know for which values of $t$ these vectors can be parallel. So we want to solve for $\lambda$, when possible, given: $$(2,1,1) = \lambda(2,t,2t).$$From the first entry, we must have $\lambda = 1$. Then the first entry gives $t = 1$. But the third entry gives us $1=2$. So they're never linearly dependent.